# VBA have a sub run another sub

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

how to run a `sub` stored in another worksheet's module?

**worksheet1**

```
sub endDay()
    'something here
end sub
```

**worksheet2**

```
sub reCalc()
    'something here
end sub
```

I want `recalc` to be able to run on its own but 
I want to be able to press the button for "endDay", have it do its thing, and then preform "recalc" at the end instead of pressing one and then go to sheet2 to press the other.

Can someone give me a sample so I can have an idea where to begin?

Comment: I do nearly all my `VBA` in workbook modules - is it essential to hide the code in the worksheet classes?

Comment: I am using Excel 2003 and it has limited options.

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at the code names for the worksheets - you can see them in the tree view in the Visual Basic Editor. Usually they are named `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc. (independent of the actual worksheet names, which are shown in brackets). Use this name in your code )instead of `Worksheets("Sheet1")`and you'll also get an autocomplete list - with your sub!

Thus, this will do the job:

```
Sheet1.reCalc
```

Answer (score 8):

```
sheets("worksheet2").reCalc
```

might be what you are after

Answer (score 2):

I know it is 2 years later, but today I was looking for the same thing. As far as the subs in the worksheets may be private, this is a good solution:

```
Sub Maina()
    Run "tbl_Input.btn_main_Click"
End Sub
```

`tbl_Input` is the VBA name of the worksheet, not the caption.

Answer (score 1):

`Call Module1.reCalc` should work as well if the Sub is in Module1. It may be unnecessary to have 'Module1.' at all though.